# Using conda to build and install local or custom R package

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I would like to install a local R package into a conda environment. The package is not on CRAN or github (and not on any conda channel).
For packages on CRAN this is relatively straightforward:

```
conda skeleton cran <pckg>
conda-build r-<pckg>
conda install --use-local r-<pcgk>
```

For packages on github this works similarly: [install R package from github using "conda"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061664/install-r-package-from-github-using-conda) (apart from some issues of versions requiring tags).

```
conda skeleton cran <url>/<pcgk>
conda-build r-<pckg>
conda install --use-local r-<pcgk>
```

However, I cannot get this to work with a local package (the package builds without problems using `R CMD build`). This is what I have tried:

```
conda skeleton cran <path>/<pcgk>
```

Connects to cran and then (of course) does not find the package.

```
conda skeleton cran --cran-url  <relative_path>/<pckg> <pckg>
```

throws an error with:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<relative_path>/<pckg>/src/contrib/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<relative_path>/<pckg>/src/contrib/?
```

```
conda skeleton cran <absolute_path>/<pckg> <pckg>
```

Throws:

```
File "/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/skeletons/cran.py", line 743, in package_to_inputs_dict
    pkg_name = re.match(r'(.*)_(.*)', pkg_filename).group(1).lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

And lastly:

```
conda skeleton cran --cran-url  <absolute_path>/<pckg> <pckg>
```

Throws:

```
 File "/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '<absolute path>/<pckg>/src/contrib/'
```

Is this not possible with conda? Or am I making a mistake?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167581/conda-build-of-r-package-on-windows-installing-package-locally) someone tried to write the skeleton files for a local package themselves, but it seems without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload your R package to your private github repository, then you could proceed with the common `conda skeleton cran <github_pckg_http_or_ssh>`.

`conda` will ask (internally by git, I think) for your password to retrieve the code.